# How can I pass an app. configuration file as an argument to a console application?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, app-config

I want to pass an application configuration file name as an argument to a console application and make it to be used as app.config file afterwards.

How can I achieve this in C#?
Thanks

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437(v=vs.110).aspx Has a pretty good example almost exactly what you are trying to do it looks like.

Comment: Downvote reason: I would expect someone with over 10k reputation to use google before asking. when I've [copied your title to google](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=How+can+I+pass+an+app.+configuration+file+as+an+argument+to+a+console+application%3F&rlz=1C1LENP_enIL564IL564&oq=How+can+I+pass+an+app.+configuration+file+as+an+argument+to+a+console+application%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57.559j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8), the 4th result is [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14465/Specify-a-Configuration-File-at-Runtime-for-a-C-Co) on code project that shows what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a string as the path to the configuration file and then use code similar to this to manually load it:

```
static Main(string[] args)
{
    var configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
    configMap.ExeConfigFilename = args[0];
    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    var value = config.AppSettings.Settings["KeyName"].Value;

    ...
}
```

Now just pass the file name to the executable.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the custom config file in the beginning of your application

   `System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(path);`
2. Get the values

   - AppSettings: `string val = config.AppSettings.Settings["key"].Value;`
   - ConnectionStrings: `string cs = config.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString;`

You could store the `Configuration` object or write a helper function.